# Commenting out some JSX code section with Emacs 27 js-mode

Tags: comment, javascript, js-mode, jsx, rjsx-mode

When I comment out (`M-x comment-dwim`) some section of JSX code with the new `js-mode` in Emacs 27, it gives:

```javascript
// <Grid rows={rows} columns={columns}>
//   <Table />
//   <TableHeaderRow />
// </Grid>
```

Is there any way to make `js-mode` behave like it does with `rjsx-mode`:

```javascript
{/* <Grid rows={rows} columns={columns}> */}
{/*   <Table /> */}
{/*   <TableHeaderRow /> */}
{/* </Grid> */}
```

Supposing that this is not currently possible, and that `js-mode` is really the way to go forward for JS/JSX code (from the older `rjsx-mode` and `js2-mode`, as I vaguely understand), where would I go to study the code and possibly suggest a pull request to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed in emacs 28.
For emacs 27 you can copy function

```
(defun js-jsx--comment-region (beg end &optional arg)
  (if (or (js-jsx--context)
          (save-excursion
            (skip-chars-forward " \t")
            (js-jsx--looking-at-start-tag-p)))
      (let ((comment-start "{/* ")
            (comment-end " */}"))
        (comment-region-default beg end arg))
    (comment-region-default beg end arg)))
```

And use it like so

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook (lambda ()
                      (when (eq js-jsx-syntax t)
                        (setq-local comment-region-function #'js-jsx--comment-region))
                      ))
```

Comment: I'm now using Emacs 28.1 and I have two problems with the new `js-mode` when I work on a JSX file: (1) since this code https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/bd67ffa1790b620b2beebdc32080d70b76e71029/lisp/progmodes/js.el#L3521 never seems to run (even though I see a `[JSX]` suffix in my modeline), the special JSX region commenting function is not used (i.e. it sill comments using `//` in a JSX section).

Comment: Second problem (2): when I activate the `js-jsx-mode` manually, the JSX region commenting is used, but then calling it through `comment-dwim` does not work with uncommenting, as it does everywhere else (i.e. I'm used to use `M-;` as a comment/uncomment toggle).

Comment: As far I know, only `rjsx-mode` and `web-mode` support uncommenting JSX region as of now. `js-jsx-mode` implementation of JSX comments is incomplete. It should probably reimplement `comment-dwim` and add a `js-jsx--uncomment-region` function a to fully support this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the [jtsx](https://github.com/llemaitre19/jtsx) package which addresses this issue.

Commenting and uncommenting JSX code is fully supported and some additional features are provided.

Note that it is implemented on top of `js-ts-mode` and `tsx-ts-mode`, which use `tree-sitter` code parser and are only available starting `Emacs 29.1`.